# What is the better way to install GCC6.1?

Tags: apt, compiling, gcc

I'm deciding which way I want to install GCC6.1.
There are two options, adding the ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test repository, and installing via apt. Or going to one of the [mirrors](https://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html) of GCC, downloading a tarball and compiling it myself.

Which of these  will give me better results? I know the tarball method will take longer, that is not a priority.

EDIT: This can be transformed into a more broad question on Installing vs Compiling.

Comment: It looks like version 6.0.1 (gcc-6-base) is available through apt (16.04 xenial). Is this version sufficient or do you need 6.1?

Comment: According to the changelog in GCC6, the name GCC-6 means 6.1, and all the new versions forward will be bugfixes. "Changelog gcc-6 (6.1.1-2ubuntu12~16.04)". 
So my question is purely Repo vs Tarball related.

Comment: I'm talking about the non-ppa version. I can't vouch for the ppa as I don't know how well maintained it is.

Comment: Oh yeah, I read your message wrong. I have to use the PPA because I'm still running Trusty. Well, Mint 17.3, of which base files are Ubuntu Trusty.

Comment: I see, this is really off topic here but is certainly on topic on http://unix.stackexchange.com and you should ask the question there for a better response from the community. With that said it is almost always recommended to install through apt-get however, as I mentioned, I don't know the reputation of this particular ppa. Please ask the question on http://unix.stackexchange.com for a better response, thanks.

Comment: I dunno if its still an issue but in times past the installed gcc wanted to match the version which the kernel was compiled on to enable seamless package updates where modules get compiled ... at a minimum I would avoid changing default gcc version when you install  newer releases ... I personally would compile the compiler and avoid apt or ppa

Comment: possibly the next release 16.10 will have gcc 6.1 so if true you could just install "Yakkety Yak" now